# Antonym of "to telescope"

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, antonyms

The verb "to telescope" conveys in a picturesque way the meaning that an elongated object  slides into itself, so that it becomes smaller. I'm looking for an equally attractive verb to convey the opposite meaning, i.e., that an elongated object extends.

Comment: Do you mean you want wa word for a _shortened_ object that extends?

Comment: I'm looking for a word for an object that extends or might extend, not necessarily a shortened object.

Comment: I wonder whether 'to telescope' could refer to both directions, getting smaller and getting longer.

Comment: @Mitch I thought the same, but all the dictionaries seem to disagree and usually give definitions similar to the following: to make or become shorter by reducing the length of the parts

Comment: I agree with Mitch. [This page on troubleshooting for a material handling crane](http://constructiontractors.tpub.com/TM-9-2320-364-34-1/0726250646.htm) lists the following problem condition: **12. BOOM DOES NOT TELESCOPE OUT OR TELESCOPES OUT SLOWLY.**

Comment: "Telescope" is bisexual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*[Untelescope](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&tbo=1&q=%22slowly+began+to+untelescope%22&btnG=)* has been used for this.

Searching with Google, though seems to show that @Eugene's suggestion of *telescope out* is quite a bit more common. If he posted this as an answer I would upvote it.

Answer (score 7):

(Transformed from comment at the suggestion of Peter Shor): Mitch had the right hunch when he wrote:

> I wonder whether 'to telescope' could refer to both directions,
>   getting smaller and getting longer

This prompted me to look on the web and indeed, there are a number of web pages that do use "**to telescope out**" (verb) in the way suggested by Mitch, for example this [page on troubleshooting for a materials handling crane](http://constructiontractors.tpub.com/TM-9-2320-364-34-1/0726250646.htm), which lists the following problem condition: 12. BOOM DOES NOT TELESCOPE OUT OR TELESCOPES OUT SLOWLY.

As an aside, while I'd be comfortable using "to telescope out", I'd feel more comfortable using "to collapse" in place of "to telescope in".

Comment: Now does "to telescope" qualify as an auto-antonym? [Interesting discussion of auto-antonyms at wordsmith.org.](http://wordsmith.org/board/ubbthreads.php?ubb=showflat&Number=1319&page=1) I would say no, because the preposition changes. (A better example of an auto-antonym is the noun "sanction", e.g., "the UN gave sanction to the arrangement" vs. "The Eiger Sanction".) In any case, in a technical text it is surely alright to use "telescope in" and "telescope out", but as I said above, if only the contractive motion is being described then I prefer "to collapse".

Comment: *collapse* is 3-D, *telescope* is linear (1-D).

Comment: @Kris The action for most collapsible objects (e.g., folding furniture) will indeed be characterized as 3-D.  However, people will also refer to (non-folding, but telescopic) cylindrical objects as collapsible, e.g., walking sticks (["collapsible walking stick"](http://about.pricegrabber.com/search.php/form_keyword=leki%20wanderfreund/skd=1)) or tent poles. There may be a twist lock or a stopper peg but such details are technical.

Comment: @EugeneSeidel I agree that using the terms "to telescope out" and "to telescope in" disambiguates the direction of telescoping. However, if only the verb "to telescope" is used most people will understand that something shrinks. The antonym I'm looking for should thus be a verb that can be used independently from the opposition in/out. My preference right now is for the verb "to untelescope" proposed by Peter Shor.

Comment: From Google, it looks like "to telescope in" as a phrasal verb very rare; usually it's just "to telescope" (which almost always means "to telescope in") or "to telescope out". (Of course, you should say something was "telescoping in and out" rather than "telescoping and telescoping out".)

Answer (score 4):

The term *to telescope* implies extending or contracting in length from within. It was coined in analogy of a telescope's barrel.

*Telescopic effect* refers to the capability of changing in length (+/-) by 'growing' or 'shrinking' along one axis, so to speak.

To convey specific meaning, we have therefore to say *telescope in* or *telescope out* as the case may be.

see also:

> [Telescoping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_%28mechanics%29) (mechanics): Telescoping in mechanics describes the
>   movement of one part sliding out from another, lengthening an object
>   ...  (from entry on Wikipedia)

Comment: I agree with this.  Even if "to telescope" generally refers to _telescoping in_, as the dictionaries apparently say, I'm having a hard time imagining an object that would telescope _in_, but wouldn't also telescope _out_.  Therefore, even with most dictionaries only mentioning the one inward direction in their definitions, I would still assume that any telescopic object was most likely _bidirectionally telescopic_.

Comment: Added reference from Wikipedia.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps *crane* or *protract* would be suitable?

Comment: *Retract* is a verb that implies folding in on itself. Like a turtle retracts its head into its shell. Or the landing gear of a plane retracts once aloft. So the opposite, *protract*, could work.

Comment: The turtle's neck does not *retract* into itself (the neck, not the tortoise), but into the shell. The neck is therefore, not telescopic; neck-shell unit could be.

Comment: @Kris, what is your point with regard to the OP's question?